# How can i write to a csv file and create a two subheaders under a header

Tags: python, csv

I want to write a two list of tuples into a csv file. each tuple contains a average monthly price and the date of that month. I want to have a two headers, Best months and Worst months and then two sub headers under each header, Date and Average price. At the moment i can write both lists into the file under the headers but it writes but the date and the average price into a single column under the header. this is the code i have so far:

```
with open('results.csv', 'w') as fo:
fieldnames = ['Best Months', 'Worst Months']
writer = csv.DictWriter(fo, fieldnames=fieldnames)

writer.writeheader()
for month in best_months:
    writer.writerow({'Best Months': month})
```

It writes the both elements of the tuple into the column under the header. there is no errors.

Comment: What are the results of the code you have posted and what problem are you having?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. For these kinds of problems, if the data is not too sensitive, please post some of it AND THEN post your desired outcome. That way, there's no need to guess what your code is trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data-structure you are describing is a CSV as follows:

Headers: Best Month, Worst Month

Where both "Best Month" and "Worst Month" consist of a tuple with the date of that month and the average price.

Elements: (Date,AvgPrice), (Date,AvgPrice)

A CSV by design does not have subheaders, you are confusing the way you are storing your data with the headers themselves. The Date and AvgPrice are properties of the "Best Month" and "Worst Month". They should not have their own subheaders.

Comment: Ok i understand that now, that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: No problem. The whole point of a CSV was to keep data processing simple. If you want to look into having sub properties or compartmentalizing your data, look towards JSON objects or XML.